# how plausible is this method of humans breathing fire?

Tags: biology, culture, fire

My method of breathing fire involves  humans stomachs producing  ethane or methane  and them  holding a lit flame  near their faces  and just breathing out of burping . Fire breathing in this is more cultural than useful.  Humans basically worship flame it self .Is this plausible or completely ridiculous. the flame would be a very small burst

Comment: Are we talking about a big ball of flames? or just like a little burst? I know people already light their farts on fire...

Comment: Well, some of the gas expelled by humans *is* combustible and *can* be set on fire. It doesn't come from the mouth, though.

Comment: @ AlexP Praise the fire pooper! Without withholding and storing those gases for release. I don’t see how this 9s going to be possible. Gases can easier leave but what is holding them back? Does burping even come from the stomach?

Comment: Wow. Can you say "bad breath?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Burping is mostly caused by gas contained in the stomach.
Methane and ethane are formed in the intestine by bacteria residing there.

Therefore if you want to have methane fed fire, you have to lit farts. Less epic, if you want. Or more, depending on your taste for epic.

If you want to lit burps, the only thing you can achieve is producing hydrogen using the hydrochloric acid contained in the stomach, by ingesting some metal.

But mind that hydrogen is a hell of burning gas: it easily explodes and its flames are not visible, since they emit UV.

Comment: And you are in danger to lit your mouth/stomach as a burb isn’t like a pressure can. Pooping isn’t either by the way. There are some risks burning yourself to some degree either way.